# Material design button with border

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I know how to make Material Design button with color fill:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
```

And no-bordered transparent button:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
```

However, is there a way to make Material design bordered (transparent inside) button? Something like below?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily by setting Material Design Button's `style` attribute to `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` and setting `app:strokeColor` attribute value to your preferred color.

example:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:text="Rounded outlined button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnRound"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

References:

- https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/
- https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Comment: Some answers were solutions for pre Material Design Button days. Now, this is the new simplest answer.

Answer (score 159):

You can also use the [**Material Components for Android**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Add [the dependency](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0' }
```

In this case you can use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md)  in your layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   ....
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
   app:cornerRadius=".."
   app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Apply the style [`@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`](http://@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton).

In your case use the **`app:cornerRadius`** attribute to change the size of corner radius. This will round off the corners with specified dimensions.
Use te attribute **`app:strokeColor`** and  **`app:strokeWidth`** to change the color and the width of the border.
[image]

You can also customize the corners using `ShapeApperance` (it requires version 1.1.0)

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/MyShapeAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyShapeAppearance" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```

The official doc is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) and all the android specs [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/).

---

With **jetpack compose** you can use the **`OutlinedButton`** and the **`border`** attribute:

```
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { },
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Blue),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp) 
    ) {
        Text(text = "Save")
    }
```

[image]

---

**OLD (support library)**

With the new [Support Library 28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#28-0-0-alpha1), the Design Library now contains the `Material Button`.

You can add this button to our layout file with:

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXX"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_android_white_24dp" />
```

You can customize the button with these attributes:

- `app:backgroundTint`: Used to apply a tint to the background of the button. If you wish to change the background color of the button, use this attribute instead of background.
- `app:strokeColor`: The color to be used for the button stroke
- `app:strokeWidth`: The width to be used for the button stroke

Also

Answer (score 33):

Here's how to do it correctly.

What you need to do is

1 - Create shape drawable with stroke
2 - Create ripple drawable 
3 - Create selector drawable for less than v21
4 - Create  a new style for button with border
5 - Apply style on button

**1 - Create shape with stroke**
`btn_outline.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent">
    </stroke>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorTransparent"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp">
    </corners>

</shape>
```

**2 - Create ripple drawable**
    `drawable-v21/bg_btn_outline.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/colorOverlay">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

`android:id="@android:id/mask"` is required to have ripple touch feedback on the button. The layer that is marked as mask is not visible on screen, its just for touch feedback.

**3 - Create selector drawable for less than v21** 
`drawable/bg_btn_outline.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_outline" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOverlay"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_outline" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOverlay"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_outline"/>

</selector>
```

**4 - Create  a new style for button with border**
 All resources that that are needed to create the style are given above, that's how your style should look like

```
<style name="ButtonBorder" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>

<style name="ButtonBorder.Accent">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_btn_outline</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
```

**4 - Apply style on button**

```
<Button
   style="@style/ButtonBorder.Accent"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

That's pretty much it. Here's a sample of how the buttons looks now. 
[image]

Comment: Where you create `btn_outline.xml` , in drawable or drawable-v21 ??

Answer (score 4):

Credits to @NomanRafique for the detailed answer! However, because of the custom background, we've lost a few important things:

1. Button's height is bigger than the default `Widget.AppCompat.Button`
2. Paddings
3. Enable/Disable states

In case you're wondering, here is how the default background looks like: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a7487e7/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-v21/abc_btn_colored_material.xml

By reusing original insets, paddings and color selectors, in a simple case we can come up with something like this (*all the values are default and come from android support/material library*) :

***drawable-v21/bg_btn_outlined.xml***

```xml
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
       android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item>
            <shape>
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material"/>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
                    android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape>
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material"/>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</inset>
```

***styles.xml***

```xml
<style name="Button.Outlined" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_btn_outlined</item>
</style>
```

At this point, we should have an outlined button that responds to touches, respects the `enabled="false"` state and of the same height as the default `Widget.AppCompat.Button`:

[image]

Now, from here you can start customizing colors by providing your own implementation of the `@color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material` color selector.

Answer (score 3):

In your XML use this,

```
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Its a button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                app:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
                app:strokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp" />
```

where

1. **app:backgroundTint** is used for background color
2. **app:strokeColor** is border color
3. **app:strokeWidth** is border width

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do buttons only with a border and the ripple effect on Lollipop and above. Just like the AppCompat buttons, these have a fallback pressed effect on lower APIs (if you need ripples on lower APIs, you need to use an external library). I use FrameLayout because it's cheap. The color of the text and the border is black, but you can change it with a custom one:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

drawable/background_button_ghost.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

If I have missed something, please leave a comment and I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid messy custom implementations. But I guess I have no other choice.

Comment: You can have it as a custom class, this is the best I've come to and I'm using it now, because it's shorter for declaration in the xml.

Answer (score 2):

#### Just use `MaterialButton` with an outline style.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:text="Delete Mentor Manager"
    app:strokeColor="@color/...."
    app:strokeWidth="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Jetpack Compose too. To do it, just create a composable function with a OutlinedButton and pass the as parameter the border you want:

```
@Composable
fun OutlineButton() {
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { //TODO - implement click here },
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Blue), // <-- border property
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(20.dp)),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(contentColor = Color.Blue)
    ){
        Text(text = "CONFIRM")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply** you can use this code. **Its looks soo Good.**

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="#F48025"
                    android:text="login"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

**Here border  color is:**

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

**And background color is:**

```
android:backgroundTint="#F48025"
```

Comment: Your solution is simple but limited. You cannot control the thickness of the border and the boarder is round inside but edged outside. Does not look good.

Comment: In my case the button is transparent

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_discussion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#80ffffff"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    style="@style/btn_start_new_discussion"
    android:text="Start new discussion" />
```

Put below code in Styles.xml file :

```
<style name="btn_start_new_discussion">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">10dp</item>
</style>
```