# android:background attribute not being applied to buttons

Tags: android, android-button, android-background

This is my very first question on StackOverflow, I expect great help from the community :)
I've looked around for this problem's solution for hours but I'm kinda puzzled..

I'm trying to create a custom outlined rounded button for my android app but when I'm applying it through the android:background attribute in XML file, It doesn't quite work. The default background color (purple) is not removed. The stroke is not applied too. However, corners are rounded.

Some say android:background is not working on MaterialButtons.  Some say create a style in themes.xml file and reapply it thru android:backgroundTint attribute (It doesn't work either).
Some say try to change it programmatically(not working too!).

Please provide an efficient solution.

Here's my code and what I'm achieving with it.

**activity_main**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**round_button**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/black" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/teal_200" />

    <corners android:radius="25dp" />

</shape>
```

Here's the result that I get
[image: Here's the result that I get]

This is what I want to achieve.
[image: This is what I want to achieve.]

I'm really looking forward to your answers! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this before and all I did was change the main theme in the file theme to Appcompat instead of the Material Theme

Comment: Yes I found this solution too. But does it have any affects? I think if MaterialComponents is by default added in our app then it may have more and better features than AppCompat.. This is what's keeping me from trying out that solution..

Comment: You can change it only for the specific activity and not for the entire app

Comment: but will that affect some specific activity if I change it to old AppCompat instead of MaterialComponenets.

Comment: It looks bad, you can use MaterialComponenets and its better features and you can also use btnImag which accepts changing the background but this is not a perfect solution. This is all I have. I hope I helped you even a little

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Shafique Ahmed,

First of all Welcome to Stack Overflow, and now to answer your question try changing your drawable file as follows and let me know  if it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item><shape>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <corners 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" 
            android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="4dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
    </shape></item>

</selector>
```

***Edit:*** You can also change one of your activity's theme from Material Components to App Compact by the following steps:

1. In the `styles.xml`(Sometimes also named as `themes.xml`) make another theme below your main one(*New theme:* App Compact while keeping the *Main theme* as Material Components) and give it any name
   2.Go the the activity file of the layout you want to change the theme of, and add then call the `setTheme(R.style.NameOfTheme);` function.

***Note:*** Call the `set theme()` function before setting the Content View (which is executed by `setContentView`)

***Edit 2:*** Try refering to
 [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395697/material-design-button-with-border) to answer your question:

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237328/discussion-on-answer-by-shaurya-goyal-androidbackground-attribute-not-being-app).

Answer (score -1):

use  `app:backgroundTint` to change your button color

Comment: This will not work for the OP as he has asked for a _transparent button with border stroke_ and not for a _simple filled one_

Comment: Tried. Didn't achieved what I want!

Comment: you can try to create a custom button with TextView.  It's easier to custom background shape.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation or delete it